# Audio issues with Sound Blaster Audigy FX PCIe 5.1 sound card on all Ubuntu-based distros

Tags: 20.04, sound, headphones, sound-blaster

I have a Sound Blaster Audigy FX PCIe 5.1 Sound Card installed and for that, on Windows, I use their sound blaster control panel. Multiple times when trying to migrate to Linux (ubuntu-based distros) I don't have access to that control panel, and end up with my sound settings sounding rather weird.

Should I instead just go with an external DAC and AMP to not worry about those sound issues, or what would a good solution to the sound issues be?

Note: I have a sound card because the built-in sound chip on my motherboard is just not strong enough to drive my headphones.

Comment: Is the control panel software required to use the hardware?  Does the hardware manufacturer publish the software for Linux/Debian/Ubuntu?  If hardware features require software to work and the software is not made available for your OS- it's unlikely that you will be able to use those features, unless someone in the community has reverse engineered software or drivers- which is sometimes not possible if everything is closed source. Your options in that case?  Complain to the manufacturer.  Don't buy hardware that needs proprietary software unavailable on your choice of OS.